# EXT JS 4.2.2 Rows in grid panel missing

Tags: extjs4.2

I'm having a really weird issue where the grid panel's height is incorrect but only on initial render. The panel has 13 items but only shows 10. If I click on the expand button the rest of the rows appear correctly. If I go to a different page then go back to the grid panel then the issue is fixed.

I found a solution that works 90% of the time by adding a set time out function and then calling dolayout

```
setTimeout(function ()
                    {
                        formpanel.down('[itemId=cont_46]').doLayout();
                    },1800)
```

Any ideas what I can do to remove this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding a RenderTo: to the gridpanel fixed the issue. I believe there was something wrong with the panel that the gridpanel was in or something.